Elasticsearch exception reason=key [types] is not supported in the metadata section
 I use ;
@Autowired
    private RestHighLevelClient client;

and function given below:
public Map<String, Object> multiCount(List<String> indices, QueryBuilder query) throws IOException {
        List<SearchRequest> requests = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String index : indices) {
            SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(index);
            searchRequest.source(new SearchSourceBuilder().query(query).size(0));
            requests.add(searchRequest);
        }
        MultiSearchRequest multiSearchRequest = new MultiSearchRequest();
        requests.forEach(multiSearchRequest::add);
        MultiSearchResponse response = client.msearch(multiSearchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
        List<Integer> countResults = new ArrayList<>();
        for (MultiSearchResponse.Item item : response.getResponses()) {
            if (item.isFailure()) {
                throw new IOException("Error in multi count request: " + item.getFailureMessage());
            } else {
                SearchResponse searchResponse = item.getResponse();
                countResults.add((int) searchResponse.getHits().getTotalHits().value);
            }
        }
        return Collections.singletonMap("counts", countResults);
    }

when ı use ;
QueryBuilder query = (QueryBuilder) matchAllQuery();

I got type=illegal_argument_exception, reason=key [types] is not supported in the metadata section. How can ı solve this error? ı can use;
CountResponse countResponse = client.count(countRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
no problem but when ı use msearch it give this error.

What version of the ES REST client are you using against which version of the ES server?

@Val ı use only spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch in spring boot dependency and ES server version 7.17.4. Also ı added some info my question.

Which version of spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch ? Make sure you're using a compatible version https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/reference/elasticsearch/versions.html

@Val actullay ı dont want to change my version. I try to use different version of spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch it s not compatible with my project.

Since all versions are hard wired from the spring-boot one, the only option is to upgrade your ES server to the one corresponding to the Spring Data ES version you're using. If it's the latest, then 8.11
